# Simple php file list - filesize not working

Tags: php

I am not very used to php, but I have made an index.php page to put in any folder of my private web server, in order to allow me to quickly download some docs. It works fine, except that I tried to add the file size. That part of the code just displays "filesize" instead of the size itself. Can someone help to fix this?

```
<h1>My tools</h1>
<?php
$dirname = ".";
$dir = opendir($dirname);

while(false != ($file = readdir($dir)))
    {
    if(($file != ".") and ($file != "..")  and ($file != "index.php"))
        {
        echo("<a href='$file'>$file</a> filesize($file) <br />");
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: readdir() is old way of doing file listings. Check out DirectoryIterator http://php.net/directoryiterator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
echo("<a href='$file'>$file</a> ".filesize($file)." <br />");
```

You can't embed anything like that. In your case PHP has no way of knowing if you want to call the `filesize` function or you just want that text printed out so it was built to interpret your format as text instead of a function call, that being the safe option.

See here for what you are allowed to put inside double quoted strings: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing

Answer (score 2):

Just writing "filesize" in a string won't execute the `filesize` function. You need to call it outside of a string literal:

```
echo("<a href='$file'>$file</a> " . filesize($file) . "<br />");
```